How to use SmallRye Fault Tolerance @Ready annotation with Smallrye Mutiny?
Currently I have a following method within my class which has been marked as @ApplicationScoped:
package org.acme;

import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.unchecked.Unchecked;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import java.util.Random;

@Path("/api/bake")
@ApplicationScoped
public class CakeResource {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CakeResource.class);
    private final Random r = new Random();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Uni<Long> bakeCake() {
        final double randomDouble = r.nextDouble();
        logger.info("****** Backing Cake Starts with random value : ******** : " + randomDouble);

        return Uni.createFrom().deferred(Unchecked.supplier(() -> {
                    try {
                        if (randomDouble < 0.5) {
                            logger.info(" No items left sorry .... ");
                            return Uni.createFrom().item(0L);
                        }

                        if (randomDouble < 0.999) {
                            logger.info(" oops Cake burned... ");
                            return Uni.createFrom().item(0L);
                        }

                        logger.info(" Cake prepared ");
                        return Uni.createFrom().item(1L);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Error checking the random value");
                    }
                }))
                .onItem()
                .transformToUni(count -> {
                    if (count < 1L) {
                        return Uni.createFrom().item(-1L);
                    }
                    return Uni.createFrom().item(count);
                })
                .onItem()
                .transformToUni(count -> {
                    if (count == -1L) {
                        return Uni.createFrom().failure(new RuntimeException("Count is less than 1 sorry unable to prepare cake"));
                    }
                    return Uni.createFrom().item(count);
                })
                .onFailure()
                .retry()
                .atMost(4)
                .onFailure()
                .recoverWithUni(failure -> Uni.createFrom().item(0L));
    }
}

The above code works fine during the failure and if something goes wrong and fails then it automatically tries up to 4+1 times.
Rather than using the retry logic within the method I want to use the SmallRye Fault Tolerance annotations such as @Retry so I changed my code and added the @Retry like this:
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Retry(maxRetries = 5)
public Uni<Long> bakeCake() {
    final double randomDouble = r.nextDouble();
    logger.info("****** Backing Cake Starts with random value : ******** : " + randomDouble);

    return Uni.createFrom().deferred(Unchecked.supplier(() -> {
                try {
                    if (randomDouble < 0.5) {
                        logger.info(" No items left sorry .... ");
                        return Uni.createFrom().item(0L);
                    }

                    if (randomDouble < 0.999) {
                        logger.info(" oops Cake burned... ");
                        return Uni.createFrom().item(0L);
                    }

                    logger.info(" Cake prepared ");
                    return Uni.createFrom().item(1L);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error checking the random value");
                }
            }))
            .onItem()
            .transformToUni(count -> {
                if (count < 1L) {
                    return Uni.createFrom().item(-1L);
                }
                return Uni.createFrom().item(count);
            })
            .onItem()
            .transformToUni(count -> {
                if (count == -1L) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error checking the random value");
                }
                return Uni.createFrom().item(count);
            })
            .onFailure()
            .recoverWithUni(failure -> Uni.createFrom().item(0L));
}

The above code does not retry during the failure and executes only once.
In the first scenario, when I was not working with @Retry during the debug, I could see the execution going to return Uni.createFrom().item(0L); multiple times during the failure.
With @Retry, it does not happen. Execution happens only once, and during the failure, @Retry does not kick in and I get existed from the method without any retries.
Based on SmallRye Fault Tolerance documentation I have tried the following:

Class is annotated with @ApplicationScoped.
Method is public.
Annotated method with @Retry.

Can someone please assist with how to use the SmallRye Fault Tolerance @Retry annotation with Smallrye mutiny Uni?
What changes do I need to make to ensure this works and does the retry during the failure?

This should work and I don't see a reason why it doesn't. If you're doing this in a Quarkus application, you can remove the @Asynchronous annotation (assuming the caller is on a worker thread), but that shouldn't affect correctness.

Afaik, fault tolerance only works with blocking code. And not with Mutiny. The latter has its own way of dealing with faults.

@Ladicek Thanks a lot for the response but unfortunately it's not working for me with @Retry. As per your instruction, I removed the @ Asynchronous and tried a couple of things and nothing worked. I have created a reproduction of the issue and provided the complete code in the above question. Can you please try it and provide some fixes?

@Ladicek From the question above, the first scenario without @Retry works fine during the failure and can perform a total of 4+1 times but in 2nd scenario with @Retry I can see it executing only once even after the failure.

@Serkan Thanks a lot for the response. That is interesting because I saw a few mentions where they have described SmallRye Fault Tolerance works with Uni but not with Multi. Even I am new to both of them so I don't have much idea so hoping to get some response or work-around on this issue.

If the question now contains actual code, then the answer is simple: the Uni never fails. See how the reactive pipeline ends with .onFailure().recoverWithUni()? That's the cause. Remove that (and add a @Fallback) and it should work.

@Ladicek Thanks a lot for the response, its working as expected.
